# What is the significance of these houses in Spirited Away?

Tags: analysis, spirited-away

In the beginning of Hayao Miyazaki's [*Spirited Away* (2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0245429/), the family drives past a dumped pile of neglected "houses for the guardian spirits".

[image]
[image]

There are two other instances of guardian spirits that are important in the story, these being the scene in which the [Unnamed River Spirit](http://spiritedaway.wikia.com/wiki/Unnamed_River_Spirit) is cleansed of all the junk and pollution, and, later on, near the end of the movie, Chihiro revealing to Haku his true name ([Nigihayami Kohaku Nushi](http://spiritedaway.wikia.com/wiki/Haku_(Nigihayami_Kohaku_Nushi))), which is where he discovers he was a river guardian - Chihiro also says the river now runs underground, since a road was built over it (this could be seen as mankind neglecting nature (and in this case, by extension, a guardian spirit) by haphazardly constructing over a river).

Knowing all this, it seems far-fetched to me that this clip where they drive past the houses is just a random, insignificant shot.

### What is the significance of the houses for the guardian spirits? Does it tie into a larger theme in the movie?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They illustrate that they are nearing a very spiritual place

This question was answered in a Reddit post:

> They're called [Hokora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokora), and they're small roadside shrines in the Shinto tradition. Here's picture of a real one:
>   [image]
>   
>   The heavy clustering of them in Ghibli movies tends to be unusual, as they are often solitary or spaced out, rather than awkwardly placed right around each other. **This is a subtle way to acknowledge to Japanese audiences that the characters are in a strange place**. Witness how Chihiro's expression intensifies when she notices them as her dad passes by in the car.
>   **Since those shrines are supposed to house kami, or spirits, a huge cluster of them indicates an area of high spiritual activity.** This is something that is likely lost on western audiences in such a specific way, but yet they still retain a strong feeling of mystery about them, even without knowing their meaning.
>   <sub>—tomrhod, [r/Ghibli (Reddit)](https://www.reddit.com/r/ghibli/comments/34j9xa/what_are_the_little_stone_spirit_houses_actually/)</sub>

The magical world they enter is inhabited by spirits, and the main location, a bathhouse, is dedicated to having the spirit guests relax and set their minds off toil and stress. Whether these houses represent a neglection of spirituality (which would be further supported by the theme reinforced in the question), or whether the spirits are there out of their own volition to "take a break", and so they possibly abandoned those houses/shrines, or whether those shrines were placed there by people aware of the nearby spirituality, or whether they got there by mystical methods, as a consequence of so much spirituality - that's left unclear.
The goal of showing the audience the pile of *hokora* was to indicate that the family is approaching a strange, mystical place with a lot of spirituality, since we see a giant amount of them, rather than the typical few.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that chihiro didn't know that 'those things' were shrines. She's a millenium kid. She's detached from her roots. And as Ghoti and Chips mentioned, it signifies that they are approaching a spiritual place. Chihiro is about to encounter something completely new.